# Flask module does not exist

Tags: python, flask

I downloaded Flask on my Windows system using

```
pip install flask
```

it says

```
Requirement already satisfied.
```

which makes sense cause i already installed it once before using easy_install.

The official Flask website says, i just need to do this to install. Yet i get the error

```
ImportError: cannot import name Flask
```

The code i used is:

```
from flask import Flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.run()
```

How can i fix this

Comment: Are you using App Engine?

Comment: No im not sure what that is.

Comment: Ok. It should work. Otherwise put in PYTHONPATH as explained here- http://scipher.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/setting-your-pythonpath-environment-variable-linuxunixosx/

Comment: Once you do sort out the importing, then you'll also want to change the following line to `app = Flask(__name__)` as you're not importing the entire `flask` module

Comment: Hey mine is a Windows system. So is there something i'm doing with installing itself. Btw i still haven't sorted out the importing

Comment: @user2596559 Could it be that you have Python 2 and Python 3 installed, and you use one but Flask is installed on the other one?

Comment: Also, what editor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem, but this code should throw a NameError. If you import the Flask class like this `from flask import Flask`, then make your app like this `app = flask.Flask(__name__)`, the interpreter will throw a NameError. You never imported flask, only the Flask class. The code should be changed to `app = Flask(__name__)` since Flask is already in the namespace.